# Accessing the value of multidimensional array java script (TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array, arguments

I have a problem when accessing the multidimensional array value through arguments, when I ran it using repl, there is no issues, but when i ran it using npm 5.6.0 and node 8.4.0, it shows the right value/output that I want ('Christ'), but after that, it shows this output with following error :

```
node exercise-2.js

[ [ 'Christ', 'Evans', 'Male', 1982 ],[ 'Robert', 'Downey', 'Male' ] ]
Christ
/Users/exercise-2.js:3

console.log(arr[0][0]);
                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at changeMe (/Users/exercise-2.js:3:21)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/exercise-2.js:47:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
```

This is the code:

```
function changeMe(arr) {
  console.log(arr);
  console.log(arr[0][0]);
}


// TEST CASES
changeMe([['Christ', 'Evans', 'Male', 1982], ['Robert', 'Downey', 'Male']]);
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error. If you're thinking you have access to `arr` outside `changeMe` *(unless you have it assigned to var arr)*, think again.

Comment: The error indicates that the `arr` you passed doesn't contain anything at the `0th` index. Can you show us the input for which you get this error?

Comment: This is the screenshot when I ran the code: https://imgur.com/a/Xdl07

Comment: i don't know where is the problem come from, is it the npm or node

Comment: Sorry, I think because I called the function for empty array. It caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both accessing the 0th and the 1st index work fine in the example you gave us. I don't see any issue here. What's the problem?

```js
function changeMe(arr) {
  console.log(arr[0][0]);
  console.log(arr[0][1]);
  return 0;
}


changeMe([['Christ', 'Evans', 'Male', 1982], ['Robert', 'Downey', 'Male']]);
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information in my question. I just updated the question. So basically the program show the right output, but after that it shows an error like I mentioned above. I don't know where the error comes from, is it the npm or node or other things.

Comment: No it wouldn't have to do with npm or node. You are giving it bad input. Judging from the output that I see, you are most likely calling `changeMe` in more than one place. Look for all occurrences of a call to `changeMe` and make sure they are all getting multi-dimensional arrays passed in

Comment: That's right, i forgot that I called it for empty array. Thank you for your help!